# ng2 initialize DOM property once and drop change detection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-template

In angular 1, I can do

```
<span ng-bind="::expression"></span>
```

to set the innerHTML of the span without creating a watcher.

In angular 2, I'm thinking of a few ways to do it but I don't know if the change detector is still alive after initialization. Since I just want to initialize the innerHTML once, it would be nice to remove change detection after first pass. Can someone help?

1. `<span [innerHTML]="expression"></span>`
2. `<span innerHTML="{{expression}}"></span>`
3. `<span>{{expression}}</span>`

And regarding 2. I found in official document that bracket can be ommitted when doing string initialization, but I don't know what happens when it's combined with {{}} interpolation.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#one-time-string-initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way how a component does **change detection**:

```
@Component({changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush})
class MyComponent {
  ...
}
```

More information: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html and http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2

Comment: Thanks for the input. The limit with ChangeDetectionStrategy seems to be that it applies to the entire template. Would it work if I only want some perperties to be "OnPush"?

Comment: Make those properties to be a part of another `Directive` or `Component`